# facebook oauth username and password authentication

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

Is there a way to use the username and password stored in  a variable be used to authenticate a user on facebook using facebook api using oauth?

If not is there a way to do so without using oauth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The whole point of using OAuth is that the user never has to give you (an untrusted third party) their password. So doing so would defeat the point.

Comment: can I achieve this without using oauth?

Comment: @koool No. Facebook's only authentication standard is OAuth (and before that, their proprietary version of OAuth) because they don't want users giving up their passwords to anyone, no matter what.